# ASP MVC Simple View not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I set up a Route in a standard MVC router in global.asax, using MapRoutes. looks like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
null, //route name
"AddUnregisteredUser/{phonenumber}", //params
new { controller = "User", action = "AddUnregisteredUserFromPhoneNumber" }
);
```

UserController.AddUnregisteredUserFromPhoneNumber returns a View that displays two ViewData["key"] values...

whenever i debug the project, and call LOCALHOST:PORT/AddUnregisteredUser/1234567890 I get nothing. I put breakpoints in teh controller function and its not even going to the controller function. I put breakpoint in the global.asax and it never sets up the route when starting the asp.net development IIS server....

I dont see what is wrong with my code. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does your controller have a default constructor? Do you have another route before it that could be catching it? For instance "{controller}/{action}/{id}"?

Answer (score 0):

Try supplying a route name instead of `null`.

Also, you might want to use RouteDebugger from [RouteMagic](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx) to verify your route definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a route name as well as add phonenumber to your route values as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "route1", //route name
  "AddUnregisteredUser/{phonenumber}", //params
  new { controller = "User", action = "AddUnregisteredUserFromPhoneNumber", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
 );
```